# Why we do need constructors?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Today my friend asked me, why really do we need constructors in C++?
Where as we can do the same in structural language.
What is the specialty of constructors, show me the need of constructors so that I should use it in my C++ program.
Please help me and give me some examples so that I could able to clear his doubt.

Comment: Why do people use contractors to build houses for them? ... because it's easier than doing it yourself.

Comment: You might suggest that your friend try writing everything in assembly.

Comment: @Marc B, you ment that the constructors by default allocate memory for all the data member variables inside a class at the time of object creation?? what is the default constructers body contains? Is the compiler inject any hidden code to the user defined constructors? If yes, how it looks like? Please explain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't *need* constructors in the same sense that you don't *need* most features of popular languages.

Constructors exist to make it more difficult to do **The Wrong Thing**.  In this case, using data that hasn't been initialized.

Comment: Agreed. Although it has added its own fully fledged features over the decades, it's worth remembering that C++ started its life as a preprocessor down to C. Constructors are an init function just like any good init function you'd write in C, but they have first class language support, so there's one less thing for users to remember, and therefore more safety than using the still-possible two-step init pattern. It's the same reason C++ works to make user generated types behave the same way as built-in types. The fewer inconsistencies, the easier it is to learn and use.

Comment: @Drew Dormann, what do you mean by "The Wrong Thing"? Please explain.

Comment: @sree in this case, "The Wrong Thing" refers to using data that hasn't been initialized.

Comment: @Drew Dormann, Please provide some more examples for "The wrong Things".

Comment: Small comment: the default constructor does not initialise the object.

Comment: @Svalbard: *"the default constructor does not initialise the object"* - it does as much as any constructor, by which I mean that it will perform the same default initialisation of bases and members, and not initialise data members of builtin types that are explicitly assigned to in the class definition nor default constructor initialisation list.  Basically, not providing a custom default constructor is the programmer's way of saying the above's sufficient initialisation for the object.

Answer (score 3):

A pathological answer is that constructors do not change the Turing completeness of the language, so, in a strict sense, you don't need them, as you don't need many features of the language.  But this is formal rather than practical.  You will be excused for not feeling warmer at night thinking only of theory.

A good practical example for why constructors are useful is to think of the RAII pattern.  By having a constructor, you encapsulate very nicely both the initialization and acquisition in the same place that you have destruction.  C, which doesn't have constructors, is famous for programmers forgetting a step in that process.

Answer (score 3):

As other people already answered, you use constructor in the same way as you would use an init function in a procedural language, but thanks to constructors there is no way the programmer will forget to call the init function - the compiler does it for him. One additional benefit this gives, aside from taking care of calling it automatically, is gracefully resolving the **inheritance** initialization problem: in case of a class A that extends class B that extends class C, you are guaranteed that all three constructors (for class A, B and C) will be called and that they will be called in the correct order (class C, then class B, then class A) so that each constructor can already use all the data from the superclass (since it has already been initialized). In the case of a language without constructors, the programmer would need to take care of all this bookkeeping.

Answer (score 0):

In a procedural language you need to initialize variables to a well defined value too. Typically with some kind of `Init` function. And a constructor is a way to ensure that when you create an object it's initialized to a valid state.

In .net you can bypass constructors(With privileged code), and you'll get an objects whose fields are initialized to 0.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the way object-oriented languages work. In C, you would use malloc to allocate memory and then initialize that memory in some way. In C++, the constructor does both things. By putting these 2 things together, this makes it harder for the developer to allocate memory and fail/forget to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Because some objects need data to initialise. With constructors you can ensure at compile-time that the object gets the data. Otherwise the compiler would throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Immutable objects.

When you are working with parallel or concurrent programming it is much easier to share objects that cannot be altered. You don't have to worry about race conditions, locks, etc. But the only way to create an immutable object in most OOP languages is via a constructor. You can't set properties on the object because, by definition, all of the properties are read-only.

Comment: But if your object is immutable, why is it an object at all? (This question is about C++.)

Comment: You may still need functionality and that functionality may be polymorphic. For example, there are read-only list interfaces in WinRT that you may want to implement in C++.