# What is the use of a constructor?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I dont exactly get the use of a constructor
For example:

```cpp
class car
{
    public:
    string name;
    long int price;
    int mileage
    bool ownedByPlayer;
};
```

Here, why will I use a constructor like this,

```cpp
class car
{
    public:
    string name;
    long int price;
    int mileage
    bool ownedByPlayer;
    car()
   { 
       ownedByPlayer = false;
   }
};
```

if I can simply define the variable `ownedByPlayer` where I have declared it. Like: `bool ownedByPlayer = false;` ?

Comment: It doesn't make very much difference for the no-args constructor, but you can write constructors that take arguments. For instance you might write a constructor `car(string name, long price, int mileage, bool owned)` that sets the values of the member variables to the values passed to the constructor.

Comment: Indeed, you don't have to. Even more, static initialization wad recommended over explicit one ever since it's been introduced.

Comment: whats the use of a constructor that does nothing useful? ... Sometimes constructors actually need to do something to construct an object

Comment: C++ didn't let you do `bool ownedByPlayer = false;` inside a class before C++11.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why we do need constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749248/why-we-do-need-constructors), [Use of constructor in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574825/use-of-constructor-in-c).

Comment: @rustyx unfortunately, both answers are quite incomplete. On the other hand, I do not think SO format is appropriate for *complete* answer to the question of the meaning of the life, **constructors** and everything.

Comment: Are you asking why this class must always have a constructor, or are you asking if you need to write that constructor yourself or if the default one the compiler generates is good enough?

Comment: So, a beginner like me should not consider any importance of constructors because I really didnt understand any usage

Answer (score 2):

In your case there is no need to write the constructor. Actually it is recommended to not write a constructor that does nothing but initialize members with default values. Though the correct way would be to use the member initializer list:

```
car() : ownedByPlayer(false) {}
```

And since C++11 you can use a default member initializer instead:

```
class car {
    // ...
    bool ownedByPlayer = false;
    // ...
};
```

---

Sometimes constructors actually need to do something. Consider a `car` registers itself somewhere after being constructed, then your class could look like this:

```
class car
{
    public:
    string name;
    long int price;
    int mileage;
    car(string name,long int price, int mileage) : name(name),price(price),mileage(mileage) {
        CarRegistrationFacility::register_car(*this);
    } 
};
```

Actually I found it difficult to make up an example for a constructor that does more than initializing members, because thats what constructors do. However, when your constructor does more than that, then that "more" happens in the body of the constructor.

Comment: The uses of constructors goes way up when you remember that you can overload them. `[std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) has like 10 constructors.

Comment: @MooingDuck good point, though I am on the edge of deleting this. maybe I'll improve it later, if the question doesn't get closed

Comment: Something like `template <typename... NameArgs, typename... PriceArgs, typename... MileageArgs> car(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<NameArgs&&...> nameArgs, std::tuple<PriceArgs&&...> priceArgs, std::tuple<MileageArgs&&...> mileageArgs)`, which I admit is total overkill for `car` as defined here?